# Best way for client to access S3 storage file in a specific bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

THanks in advance....
I would like to provide security for al my URLS of s3 bucket.IN my bucket around 10 files are there and each file is to be restricted to limited users.Dont want make my server as proxy for validation to access the files..please help me with best way to solve this.

Ex:
File to be accessed by only 3 users & FIle2 to be accessed by 5 users.but all files in same bucket.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a perfect use-case for [IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/). By using JSON syntax you can easily restrict access to AWS Resources (including S3 bucket, key).

Example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/Alice"
      } 
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/file1"
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...App server generating the URL and sending to client.Can S3 validate sender is the right end user requested for donwload file.My App server to send URL to many clients to download file from S3.How this can be taken care to avoid intruder who got the URL and try to access URL.What do we need to do to make S3 validate this some how?...Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the IAM policies, you can white list IP address